# Using LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle with an LDAP Provider

Tags: ldap, lexikjwtauthbundle, symfony-4.4

I have a project that use Symfony API-Platform. I want to use LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle on my  project but my users are stored in an Active Directory  so I set an LDAP UserProvider. I tried to combine the setting of the two following documentation without success :

- https://api-platform.com/docs/core/jwt/
- https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/ldap.html

Here is what I have done

In security.yml :

```
security:
    providers:
        my_ldap:
            ldap:
                service:     Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                base_dn:     OU=organization_unit,DC=domain,DC=local
                search_dn:   "OU=organization_unit,DC=domain,DC=local"
                search_password: '%env(resolve:LDAP_PASSWORD)%'
                default_roles: ROLE_USER
                uid_key: uid
firewalls:
    login:
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        json_login:
            provider: my_ldap
            check_path:               /api/login_check
            success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

    api: 
        pattern:   ^/api/
        stateless: true
        guard:
            provider: my_ldap
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

In services.yml :

```
Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap:
    arguments: ['@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter']
Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter:
    arguments:
        -   host: '%env(resolve:LDAP_HOST)%'
            port: 636
            # encryption: tls
            options:
                protocol_version: 3
                referrals: false
```

But when I try to send the request to my_domain/api/login_check with following content :

```
{
  "username": "my_user",
  "password": "my_password"
}
```

I received this error as response:

```
{"code":401,"message":"Invalid credentials."}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issue by using a custom action that checks if the user exist using LDAP and get its roles. Then, if the freshly retrieved user is authorized to use the application, I create a new token and return it in the response. And finally the token is used to authentify the user for each call he do to the API.

Here is my security.yml

```
providers:
    # provider to retrieve user from LDAP
    my_ldap:
        id: App\Security\LdapService
    # provider to retrieve user from user
    jwt:
        lexik_jwt:
            class: App\Security\User
firewalls:
    login:
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
api: 
        pattern:   ^/api/
        stateless: true
        guard:
            provider: jwt
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

The login action in controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/login", name="api_login", methods={"POST"})
 */
public function loginCheck(Request $request, LdapService $ldapService, AuthenticationSuccessHandler $authenticationSuccessHandler, AuthenticationFailureHandler $authenticationFailureHandler){
    $content = json_decode($request->getContent());
    $response= new JsonResponse();
    try{
        $user=$ldapService->authenticate($content->username, $content->password);
        return $authenticationSuccessHandler->handleAuthenticationSuccess($user);
    }catch(AuthenticationException $e){
        return $authenticationFailureHandler->onAuthenticationFailure($request, $e);
    }        
    return $response;    
}
```

Comment: Can you share your LdapService class?