Symfony how to make user creation after ldap login?
I have got a 2 auth methods: basic by register for local db, and also by ldap active directory. Operations in my app need to take user, and also i need save user after his first ldap authorize in my db, how can i do that?
It's my controllers:
    #[Route(path: '/ldap/login', methods: ['POST'])]
    #[OA\RequestBody(
        content: new OA\JsonContent(
            ref: new Model(type: LogInRequest::class),
            type: 'object'
        )
    )]
    public function ldapLogin(): void
    {
    }

security.yaml
        company_ldap:
            ldap:
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                base_dn: "base_dn"
                search_dn: "search_dn"
                search_password: "search_password"
                uid_key: uid

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login:
            pattern: ^/api/auth/login
            stateless: true
            provider: users
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/auth/login
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        ldap_login:
            pattern: ^/api/auth/ldap/login
            stateless: true
            provider: company_ldap
            json_login_ldap:
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                dn_string: 'dn_string'
                check_path: /api/auth/ldap/login
                login_path: /api/auth/ldap/login
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

I also tried to write auth service:
    public function signUpLDAP(LogInRequest $logInRequest, array $ldapAttributes): IdResponse
    {
        $email = $ldapAttributes['mail'];
        $user = $this->userRepository->existsByEmail($email);

        if (!$user) {
            $user = (new User())
                ->setFirstName($ldapAttributes['givenName'] ?? '')
                ->setLastName($ldapAttributes['sn'] ?? '')
                ->setEmail($email)
                ->setRoles(['ROLE_USER']);

            $user->setPassword($this->hasher->hashPassword($user, $logInRequest->getPassword()));

            $this->em->persist($user);
            $this->em->flush();
        }

        return new IdResponse($user->getId());
    }

But what to do next i don't know....

Hi, have a look to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59989293/using-lexikjwtauthenticationbundle-with-an-ldap-provider
